# Adjust the scrolling speed when scrolling by dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page on a website i am working on, that includes many images in a div in a grid (map). I made the div show a scroll bar at overflow and used jquery to enable scrolling via dragging and it works as intented with only a hundred or so showing at a time. 
My only issue is, that since there are thousands of small images, moving the mouse only a bit will already result in blowing past a lot of objects.
My question now is, how can i modify my code, so that moving the mouse over the screen once will only scroll about one tenth of the div's width. So basically i want to reduce the scrolling speed. 
I am super new to javascript etc. so please be patient.

```
<div id="map" class="center unselectable overflow">
lots of images here in a grid</div>

<script>
var clicked = false, clickY, clickX;
var map = document.getElementById('map');
$(document).on({
    'mousemove': function(e) {
        clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
    },
    'mousedown': function(e) {
        clicked = true;
        clickY = e.pageY;
        clickX = e.pageX;
    },
    'mouseup': function() {
        clicked = false;
        $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');
    }
});

var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
    $('html').css('cursor', 'row-resize');
    $(map).scrollTop($(map).scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY));
    $(map).scrollLeft($(map).scrollLeft() + (clickX - e.pageX));
}
</script>
```

TLDR: how to I reduce the drag to scroll speed in jQuery?

Comment: If you want to reduce the scrolling speed, simply reduce the value you feed to `.scrollTop()` and `.scrollLeft()`, e.g. divide them by a certain factor. The factor is to be arbitrarily determined.

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick, i thought about that already, but i divided the wrong variable. But your solution does exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Glad that the solution worked. I've reworked my comment into an answer, with some additional notes and explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more elabouration from my comment: it seems like you are trying to **dampen** the scrolling speed. Mathematically, this means all you need is to reduce the value you feed to the `.scrollTop()` and `.scrollLeft()` functions. This can be done by dividing them by a set, arbitrarily determined factor, so that the transformation is linear. An example will be, if you want to dampen your scrolling speed by a factor of 10×, then you simply divide the values by 10:

```
var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $(map).scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY);
    var scrollLeft = $(map).scrollLeft() + (clickX - e.pageX);

    $('html').css('cursor', 'row-resize');
    $(map).scrollTop(scrollTop / 10);
    $(map).scrollLeft(scrollLeft / 10);
}
```

Pro-tip: since you are accessing `$(map)` several times, you can (micro)optimize your code by caching it:

```
var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
    var $map = $(map);

    var scrollTop = $map.scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY);
    var scrollLeft = $map.scrollLeft() + (clickX - e.pageX);

    $('html').css('cursor', 'row-resize');
    $map.scrollTop(scrollTop / 10);
    $map.scrollLeft(scrollLeft / 10);
}
```